# Passing parent parameters to child build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have dabbled with `Parameterized Trigger Plugin` but haven't had any luck. What I am basically looking to achieve is pass over the parent job's parameters to the child job. In my parent job, I have defined a variable `var` whose value at run time I want to be able to pass to the child job `Test_child`.

[image]

[image]

In my child job `Test_child`, following is the set-up:-

[image]

And when I echo the same parameter variable in the child job, I don't see any values being passed on.

Answer (score 3):

In parent job under `Post-build Actions` you are using `Trigger parameterized build on other projects` plugin which is the right method but you are not passing any parameter. You need to add parameter as shown in below image
[image]

So whatever value is present in `var` it will be passed to child job and in your case i.e. `Test_child` and you can use the same variable `var` in `Test_child`.

Comment: still the same, despite the assignation to a variable. Makes me wonder if I have missed any settings in the `child job`.

Comment: In `Test_child` why are you using `Build after other projects are build` ? It seems to be redundant as you have already configured the same in parent job in `Trigger parameterized build on other projects`. Please remove it and see

Comment: agreed, although, previously there were issues with the child job getting triggered without it. Anyway, I have since your response done the change but don't see the parameter value cascading.

Comment: I'm also using the same plugins and it is working for me. Earlier there was this same issue in Jenkins, see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34873 but it is fixed. check it out

Comment: One more thing in `Execute shell`can you use like this `echo $var".

Comment: @BalajeeAddanki - any solution to report? I'm facing a similar problem with the same plugin.

Comment: @ben_979, nope,  I haven't