# how pass email in jenkins in run time through Variable

Tags: email, jenkins

I am facing below problem,Appreciate if any one help

I am having jenkin job which will trigger java jar contains code to read the email from excel and the same email to be passed in jenkins for sending email in username  field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [parameterized jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832419/how-can-i-create-parameterized-jenkins-job) (If you want to manually trigger it)?

If, you want to read from excel and pass to another job please take a look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626836/passing-parent-parameters-to-child-build-in-jenkins)

Comment: I would like to pass the value which is retrieved from excel to be passed  it in same job

Comment: @RavindraRayapuneni I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. If the sole purpose of your job is emailing, the why not make your code read the excel file itself?
Or else, if you want a job that's only supposed to send an email then make a parameterized one that accepts Email ID, Subject etc and trigger it from a parent job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your problem:
1. Jenkins to trigger emails to DevOps team that the deployment task results
2. Application to trigger emails that the application is being deployed successfully (Or any other scenarios you want to achieve, please indicate, and I will try to enhance this post)

If above is the case, you should try to utilize Jenkins to complete the full process: build, test, deploy and verify, then consolidate the results then send out via email

It's a clear cut that Jenkins for deployment and app for business

There are different ways to verify your application is deployed successfully depends on how you identify if app deployment is successful.
Jenkins can detect those signals, e.g. send a ping or curl to the application and verify the response

Now only Jenkins needs to know the list of emails address for the deployment results, you can use [parameterized jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832419/how-can-i-create-parameterized-jenkins-job) as @Avneesh Srivastava mentioned